# template layout for PugJs

Tags: node.js, pug

I used NodeJs with Handlebars and thought about switching to PugJs because some functionality is native - using Handlebars requires some helper functions / partials.

In Handlebars I have to define a layout and pass in the template. In PugJs I created two example routes

**First route file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        template: 'main'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Second route file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Page2',
        template: 'pageTwo'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see I always have to render my index file and pass in the desired pug file as a template variable.

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  include ./header.pug
  body
    include ./templates/#{template}.pug
```

**header.pug**

```
head
  title #{title} template!
```

**main.pug**

```
script(src='./client/main.js')
h1 main content here
```

**pageTwo.pug**

```
p pageTwo
```

When rendering the pug files I get this error

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '...\views\templates\#{template}.pug'

How can I replace `#{template}` with the correct template variable?

Comment: Pug doesn't support dynamic `include` statements, unfortunately.

Comment: hm it seems there is no chance for using it then ...

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic template selection isn't a feature of pug, I believe it has something to do with how pug pre-compiles everything into a JavaScript function that stays in-memory inside node.js when it runs.  The benefit of that is super-fast page rendering, so we're happy to keep using pug and just work around this.

Speaking of which, you can accomplish what you want to do using [conditional logic](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html):

```
doctype html
html
  include ./header.pug
  body
    if template === 'pageOne'
      include ./templates/pageOne.pug
    else if template === 'pageTwo'
      include ./templates/pageTwo.pug
    else
      include ./templates/home.pug
```

You should also look into the [extends feature](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) to simplify adding the header into your templates and [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) to resuse code between templates.  You might find that these features could provide a better solution to your requirements with some redesign.